# java: Calling method A in method B that is initially callid in A, NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

I am writing a java application, that can write a text file.

In the main the user is asked for some options by a scanner. One of them is to add certain content in the file. This is done by calling a

```
static void OptionMenu()
```

method, which utilizes  a switch case algorithm.

By choosing a certain option, a next method (e.g. writing file), a

```
static void write()
```

is called.
This method utilizes scanners.

Now if I add the code

```
OptionMenu()
```

(to return to the option menu) at the end of write(), the code runs till this line and I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
```

But if i delete the code at the end to call the method OptionMenu() again, I get no error and the desired file is written.

However, I want to be able to go back to the option menu and give the user the possibility to execute another option, so I don't want the application to exit.

I hope someone can provide a solution. See the relevant port of code below.
Thanks in advance!

Regards,

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class WoningApplicatie 
{ 
 private static Portefeuille portefeuille = new Portefeuille();

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String options =
            "1) Voeg koopwoning toe" + "\n" +
            "2) Voeg huurwoning toe" + "\n" +
            "3) Laat huurwoningen zien" + "\n" +
            "4) Laat koopwoningen zien" + "\n" +
            "5) Sluit de applicatie";
    Println("Kies één van de volgende opties");
    Println(options);
    Println("");

    OptionMenu();

    //System.out.println(portefeuille.getWoningen().size());


}



/** Laat je uit één van de beginoptie's kiezen.
 * 
 */
static void OptionMenu()
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Print("Voer nu het optienummer in: ");
    int keuze = input.nextInt();

    switch (keuze)
    {

        case 1:
            //Voeg Koopwoning toe
            write();

            //try
            //{
                OptionMenu();
            //}catch(Exception e)
            //{ Println("kan toch niet?");
            //}

            break;
        case 2:
            Println(keuze);//Voeg huurwoning toe
            break;
        case 3:
            Println(keuze);//Laat Koopwoning zien
            break;
        case 4:
            Println(keuze);//Laat huurwoning zien
            break;
        case 5:
            Println(keuze);//Sluit de applicatie
            break;
        default:
            Println("Fout! Probeer het opnieuw. Kies één van de opties (1-5)");
            OptionMenu();
            break;
    }
    input.close();
}


static void write()
{
    Scanner woningToevoeg = new Scanner(System.in);

        try 
        {   
            Print("Straat: ");
            String straat = woningToevoeg.next();
            Print("Huisnummer: ");
            String huisnummer = woningToevoeg.next();
            Print("Postcode: ");
            String postcode = woningToevoeg.next();
            Print("Woonplaats: ");
            String woonplaats = woningToevoeg.next();
            //Adres 

            Print("aantal kamers: ");
            int kamers = woningToevoeg.nextInt();
            Print("koopprijs: ");
            int koopprijs = woningToevoeg.nextInt();
            //Woning

            Print("Energielabel (A-E): ");
            String energielabel = woningToevoeg.next();

            woningToevoeg.close();

            Adres adres = new Adres(straat, huisnummer, postcode, woonplaats);
            KoopWoning koopwoning = new KoopWoning(adres, kamers, koopprijs,"TE KOOP", energielabel);
            portefeuille.voegtoe(koopwoning);


            //This is the content to write into file
            String contentPre = portefeuille.getWoningen().size() + "\r\n";                 
            String content = koopwoning.getStatus() + "\r\n"
                    + adres.getStraat() + " " + adres.getHuisnummer() + "\r\n"
                    + adres.getPostcode() + " " + adres.getPlaats() + "\r\n"
                    + koopwoning.getKamers() + " kamers" + "\r\n"
                    + "vraagprijs " + koopwoning.getVraagPrijs() + "\r\n"
                    + "energiepeil " + koopwoning.getEnergiePeil() + "\r\n";

            File file = new File("portefeuille.txt");

            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
                if (!file.exists()) 
                {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }
            Scanner searchEmpty = new Scanner(file);

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            bw.write(contentPre);
                if(searchEmpty.hasNextLine());
                {

                    String random = ""; 
                    while(!random.isEmpty())
                    {
                        random = searchEmpty.nextLine();
                    }
                    bw.write(content);
                }

            bw.close();
            searchEmpty.close();

            Println("U heeft een woning toegevoegd!");

        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
///... some other code: Println methods for example,
}
```

Comment: "I hope someone can provide a solution." - doubtful because you haven't provided any code.

Comment: I simply described the contents and structure of my code, and explained exactly the point that causes the error. The rest of code doesn't cause this error, so it's irrelevant. But I can add the basics of the code if you would think this is "really" necessary.

Comment: You're asking about a problem that you're having with your code - *so it's **the most relevant thing you could provide***.

Comment: I'm having problems with **part** of my code, so this **part of the code** is the relevant problem, which I **did** provide.

Comment: If you think that all you need to diagnose a problem in code is the single line that's failing then good luck to you.

Comment: There you go. See if you find anything useful in there?

Comment: The first thing that strikes me is that you're not consuming the newline character left in the Scanner input buffer after each call to `nextInt()`. If you don't manually get rid of it, subsequent calls to `next()` or `nextLine()` will appear to be skipped (they aren't, they just immediately grab an empty input because of the leftover newline). Add a throwaway call to `nextLine()` after each `nextInt()` call and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not closing both the 'input' Scanner and the 'woningToevoeg' Scanner stopped the error from ocurring.